# Show javascript code in php, coming from an textarea

Tags: javascript, php, json, html

I need the user to enter a complete code in a textarea, it appears in php programming ...

In the code this is with error cutting the parameters adding "[removed]", the input of the code was tested and it is ok, but to appear the code happens this conversion ...

**Simple code entry:**

```
    public function addchat($el) {
    $conteudo = $el['ed_json'];
    $echohtmladdchat = $conteudo['zcodigo'];

    return $echohtmladdchat;
}
```

**The code insert:**

```
<!--Start of Zendesk Chat Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?2SkHVyd50jJGoAuy5eKmVqknfvdGQpRM";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e.parentNode.insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
</script>
<!--End of Zendesk Chat Script-->
```

**As the code appears:**

```
&lt;!--Start of Zendesk Chat Script--&gt;
[removed]
window.$zopim||(function(d,s){var z=$zopim=function(c){z._.push(c)},$=z.s=
d.createElement(s),e=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];z.set=function(o){z.set.
_.push(o)};z._=[];z.set._=[];$.async=!0;$.setAttribute("charset","utf-8");
$.src="https://v2.zopim.com/?2SkHVyd50jJGoAuy5eKmVqknfvdGQpRM";z.t=+new Date;$.
type="text/javascript";e[removed].insertBefore($,e)})(document,"script");
[removed]
&lt;!--End of Zendesk Chat Script--&gt;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Comment: if you want to implement zopim chat on your site then put zopim script in footer html file

Comment: It is escaping html characters, how do you output the code? and where do you save it? database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the code use `echo htmlentities($js);`

Comment: @FabioMaximoChagas please shift your comment to inside your question so that readers don't have to search the entire page for the full story.

Comment: @getl0st Please improve your answer with some more explanation.  Your answer is currently in the moderation queue because it was flagged as "low-quality".

Comment: I changed it but still it does appear [removed], I needed the code to appear by full, as I showed here in the post...